# Converting Excel spreadsheet to xml - force empty tags to be output as <tag></tag>

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am converting a excel sheet into xml format. The problem I am facing is that I have many fields which do not have any data. For those, I'm getting a blank tag like this:

```
<event-name />
```

What I want is that this tag should be in this format:

```
<event-name></event-name>




string Title                = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["title"].ToString();
                string Shortdescription     = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["short-description"].ToString();
                string sampleimageshref1    = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["sampleimageshref"].ToString();
                string sampleimageshref2    = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["sampleimageshref1"].ToString();
                string variantshref1        = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["variantshref1"].ToString();
                string variantshref2        = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["variantshref2"].ToString();
                string start                = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["life-cyclestart"].ToString();
                string end                  = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["life-cycleend"].ToString();
                string contentcpid          = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["content-cp-id"].ToString();
                string Keyw                 = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["keywords"].ToString();
                string categoriesref1       = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["categoriesref1"].ToString();
                string categoriesref2       = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["categoriesref2"].ToString();
                string Moviename = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["movie-name"].ToString();
                string actorname = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["actor-name"].ToString();
                string lyricist = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["lyricist"].ToString();
                string singername = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["singer-name"].ToString();
                string Label = dsPushTable.Rows[i]["label"].ToString();











                Directory.CreateDirectory(xmlFilePath);
                XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFilePath + "/" + Title + ".xml", Encoding.Unicode);
                xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("MP3Tone"); //Root Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("title"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(Title); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("short-description"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(Shortdescription); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("provider"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ref"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("/data/cp_ref/techzone.ContentProvider"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("sample-images"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("href"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(sampleimageshref1); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("transcodable"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("False"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("sample-images"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("href"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(sampleimageshref2); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("transcodable"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("False"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("variants"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("href"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(variantshref1); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("transcodable"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("False"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("variants"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("href"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(variantshref2); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("transcodable"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("False"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();  //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();  //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("status"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("Submit"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("life-cycle"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("start"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(start); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("end"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(end); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("content-cp-id"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(contentcpid); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("keywords"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(Keyw); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("categories"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ref"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(categoriesref1); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("categories"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ref"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(categoriesref2); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("bearer-type"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("bearer-2g"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("True"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("bearer-2.5g"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("True"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("bearer-3g"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("True"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("charge-code"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("CHC01500"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("right-owner"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("/data/rights123.RightsOwner"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ingestion-timestamp"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(start); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("delivery-methods"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("wap"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("True"); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("web"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("sms"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("movie-name"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(Moviename); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("actor-name"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(actorname); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("lyricist"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(lyricist); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("singer-name"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(singername); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("event-name"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("composer-Name"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element



                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("isrc-code"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("all-region"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString("True"); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("label"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(Label); //Attribute Value 

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("approved-timestamp"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                xmlWriter.WriteString(""); //Attribute Value 
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element


                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();//End artists Element



                xmlWriter.Flush();
                xmlWriter.Close();
```

Comment: `<event-name />` is valid xml, are you sure you need the other format?

Comment: yaa dear....actually i needed to upload that xml file...so while uploading its only accepting that format...direct closing tag its not accepting...according to requirement only i need to work....i know that is also a correct format...but i need the second one...please provide me any solution

Comment: Well how are you converting to xml ?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere? However, in xml you have to be working at a very low level to notice a difference between the two; they are essentially equivalent.

Comment: i know that they both are equivalent..but i need to fulfill client requirement ..he is not able to understand this...so if the requirement forces me to get this type of tag only that time what i need to do...please help me out if there is any solution for this...

Comment: @AshuRawat side point: it may be an "E2L" thing, but a lot of people object to being called "dear". I notice this usage increasingly  lately - it is like some language school has been encouraging it... but it doesn't usually go down well, to be honest.

Comment: frankly, the key part here is: how you are writing the xml (i.e. what V4Vendetta asked); so : how *are* you generating the xml?

Comment: xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("title"); //Attribute "partnerProductId"
                    xmlWriter.WriteString(Title); //Attribute Value 
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //offering Element       I can not send u the whole code...because its taking only limited characters...this is the sample of creating a single tag

Comment: @AshuRawat you can hit "edit" to add longer examples to the question

Comment: check the code..its a combined code...sorry for this..i m new here so facing all these problems...

Comment: @MarcGravell please go through my code...and add some solution in that code...your solution code is not working for my code...

Comment: @AshuRawat define "not working". You do of course need to use `new CustomWriter(...)` instead of new `XmlTextWriter(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `WriteFullEndElement` instead of `WriteEndElement`.

Comment: wow; I've never stumbled into this little method (after plenty of xml), yet it does exactly what we want here. Great spot.

Comment: thanks. it still closes the element on different lines if formatting is set to indent. But I doubt that will break any xml reader software though.

Comment: great answer...this is what i want...and it solves my problem...thats @ajakblackgoat...thanx a lot for your support....and thanx to all also..for giving me dis much support...